# Modifing Search Query For Site Search

Tags: php, mysql, search-engine

I am working on site search engine i am able to do searches, now i want to modify query so as to make a smart search.

I am writing my query like this

```
    require_once('../global/connect.php');
$db = mysql_select_db($database,$connection) or trigger_error("SQL", E_USER_ERROR);
$sqlquery = mysql_query("SELECT title FROM test_table WHERE MATCH (title) AGAINST ('%keyword*%' IN BOOLEAN MODE) ")or die (mysql_error());
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sqlquery)){
echo $row['title'];
echo"</br>";
}
```

I want a search functionallity that can search like.

if user type any of these keywords

```
KEYWORDS
KEY-WORDS
KEY-WORDS
KEY WORDS
KEYWORD
KEYWOR
```

result should be same.

I have looked around many question here like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406587/php-mysql-advanced-search-page?rq=1). and goggled it, also looked at MySQL developer website [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html), but i cant get any idea how to modify my query to get it work.

Please suggest any possible approach to this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try [`SOUNDS LIKE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#operator_sounds-like):

```
SELECT title FROM test_table WHERE title SOUNDS LIKE '%keyword*%'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using Lucene for doing searches. It supports fuzzy matching. Also, you'll have less load on your database.

Comment: i have shared server, i cannot go for Lucene of Sphinx.